# How do you set the default device in the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Every time I switch Xcode between debugging on my iPhone and running in the simulator it resets the simulated device. I want to run the simulator as an iPhone device, but it keeps changing back to iPad. Does anyone know how to set the configuration so that the simulator defaults to an iPhone device?

I can switch the hardware to iPhone inside the Simulator, but when I go back to Xcode and run a "Build Debug" it reopens the app inside an iPad. The only way I can get it to switch is by using the Overview menu in Xcode, the choices I see are iPad Simulator 3.2 and iPhone Simulator 4.0

And when I switch between device and simulator then it always goes back to iPad.

Comment: Where is this "Overview menu in Xcode,"? Not obvious

Comment: @michela: There's a drop-down menu in the top-left of the window, just under the traffic-light buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the Base SDK set to in your project (General tab)?  If it's not 4.0 then I think it may assume you are writing an iPad app.

If you set it to 3.2 wanting to support iOS 3.x, you need to set the base SDK to 4.0, then go into project build settings tab and change the OS Deployment target to 3.1 (or whatever the earliest version is you want to support).

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem, that is each time it is changing to iPad(4.2). I havn't find any option for selecting other than 4.2 in the General tab. I am using xcode3.2.5. Can you please help me.

Comment: You have to select 4.2 in General, then go into the Build tab and look for "Deployment Target".  Set that to 3.1 (or 4.0).

Comment: It should with with XCode 4 and the 4.2 SDK.  You can still set a base target (now you have the option of "latest SDK" that you should always use) and then also a deployment target in Build Settings.

Answer (score 11):

I got XCode 4 to launch the iPhone simulator instead of the iPad simulator by doing this:

1. In the "Product" menu, pick "Edit Scheme".
2. Single-Click "Run *Your_Project_Name* Debug" from the list on the left of the scheme editing window.
3. At the top of the window notice that the pull-down above "Destination" is set to "iPad 4.3 Simulator".
4. Change the pull-down to "iPhone 4.3 Simulator".
5. Click "OK".

Comment: To set [default devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091411/5941807)

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 9 you can select multiple devices. However an easy way to default to your favorite device is the following:

1. Choose your device from simulator-hardware-device-os you are working on
2. Now go to simulators - windows and turn off “ show device bezel”
3. Now simply close the ones you don’t want

Answer (score 2):

in iOS simulator go to :

**File** / **Open Device** / **iOS 'versión'** in my case (iOS 13.7) / **Select the one you need**

next time you open the simulator will be open with the device selected.

Answer (score 1):

In the iPhone Simulator, go to Hardware>Device, and select "iPhone".  Whatever you choose there is automatically saved.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem - that is how i found this thread.

in `SDK 4.2` make sure that when you open the a new xcode project you choose `Product = 'iPhone'` - the default selection is Ipad. Then when you save the project the device settings are saved with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on XCode Version 14.3.1. Go to Product->Destination->Manage Run Destinations... From this page, you can customize the 'Show run destination' section. Just change the ones you don't want to simulate as 'never' and change the preferable one as 'always'. For your case, under the device section find your phone (it is already selected), change the Show run destination as always, go to simulators find the iPad model, and change its show run destination as never.