# Can I set the default simulator for new projects in Xcode 7.1 or latest?

Tags: xcode

I've been making a ton of new projects as I'm learning Swift. My development is all on my laptop, so I hate using the default 6s Plus simulator, since the window is too big to easily see. Is there a way to change the default simulator to be a different one for new projects?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question. It is unfortunate that the answer seems to be no.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No need to delete simulators!

1. Product → Destination → Add Additional Simulators...

[image: Click on "Add Additional Simulators"]

2. In the sidebar, select the simulator you want to hide

[image: List of iOS simulators]

3. Uncheck "Show as run destination"

[image: New "Show as run destination" checkbox]

Edit: Updated for Xcode 10

Comment: I wonder why this is marked as the answer when it doesn't answer how to set a default simulator. I want to set one sim as a default and still keep the other sims for when I need to simulate other devices...

Comment: To set the default, go to Product --> Destination --> Choose Destination and choose from the list. That works for me in Xcode 12

Answer (score 15):

You can select the desired simulator via the Hardware > Device > [OS] menu (Xcode 9):

[image]
While unchecking "Show as run destination" hides the simulator, this will also change the default value.

UPD for Xcode 11.5
[image]

UPD for Xcode 14.3
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Xcode 9 UPDATE:

In Xcode 9, no need to delete simulators, and the way to turn them on/off is to go in Product/Destination/Add Additional Simulators... select the simulator you want to turn off, then uncheck the box: 'Show as run destination'

[image: choose or change Xcode default simulator]

Comment: It still doesn't let you choose the one on startup, but it's nicer than deleting it.

Comment: Window menu > Devices and Simulators will get you to the same place. It would have been nice if they allowed multiple-selection updates.

Answer (score 12):

No. But...

- If you don't like the size of the 6s plus simulator, make it smaller with the simulator Window Scale menu.
- If you don't like the 6s plus simulator at all, delete it with the Xcode Window Devices menu.

Comment: I just deleted it. Would have been nicer to be able to set default simulator for new projects.

Comment: This is also the only solution I've been able to come up with. Unfortunately, I do need to test on a 6/6s/7+ device sometimes, so deleting it is inconvenient.

Comment: @GregBrown I totally agree. You should file an enhancement request with Apple! bugreport.apple.com. There should be a way to set the default simulator.

Comment: Also, if you don't like to have a million of simulators in the drop-down menu, make the latest SDK the Deployment Target. If you don't like the iPad simulators, make your app iPhone-only :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Xcode 12.5**

In Xcode, go to *Product -> Destination -> Choose Destination* menu and selecting the device you'd like to be your default.
The original answer could be found in apple support forum here: [Apple support forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687857),
In addition if you want to make the device smaller just hover over bottom right corner of the simulator and you will see the resize option

[image: "Product/Destination/Choose Destination"]

[image]

Comment: This should be marked at the correct answer. Thank you - now I don't have to hardcode the device in every View_Preview function.

Comment: @esbenr I am curious! how to do that ? can you please elaborate your way?

Comment: @AayushShah Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/ios/simulator?tabs=vsmac

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the simulators you don't want will default you to the simulator you do want. I also develop on my laptop and the biggest simulator I can see w/o scaling down is the 4S, so I deleted simulators for iPhone 5 and above and now every project I create defaults to 4S simulator. If I ever need the newer simulators, I will just re-download.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just select the device in Product → Destination, Xcode 12.4

Answer (score -1):

**Xcode version 11.5**

On Simulator > File > Open Device > iOS 13.5 > Change the default Simulator

[Xcode(v11.5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbUgW.jpg)

Comment: Open Device option not available under File

Comment: @SaikatSaha, not under Xcode's File, under Simulator's File. This unfortunately doesn't actually solve the original question though.

Answer (score -2):

open your simulator, choose **File/Open Device/iOS 13.5/iPhone8 ** will change your simulator device to iPhone 8.
When you reopen your simulator, iPhone 8 will be your device simulator.

Comment: please provide a proper instructions