# Changing default simulator device in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Every time, when I'm opening a new project in xcode it showing the default simulator device as iPhone 8plus. So, I'm changing the device to iPhoneX every time before running. Is there any way to it as default for any project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577934/can-i-set-the-default-simulator-for-new-projects-in-xcode-7-1