# How to set default simulator device in Xcode 10 which is used for new projects

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I'm using Xcode 10. I normally set iPhone 5S to be default device on simulator. When I create/open a new/other project by default it set iPhone XR as default device.

I'm aware that I can hide devices which I don't want by unchecking "Show as run destination" but it's not the ideal solution.

I want all new/existing projects in Xcode to set iPhone 5S as default simulator. Is it possible? After all it's already setting iPhone XR as default, where is it set?

Comment: It's not duplicate as the solution which those answer describe are unchecking box which I've already explained in my question that I don't want to do it. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I just turn on iPhone5s and turn off the default iPhone XR through Window -> show device bezels

Comment: This is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277759/3994029