# Xcode - always select "iPad Pro 11" as the simulator when opening a new project

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

[image: pre-selected device]

I'd like to have `iPad Pro (11-inch)` (or any other specific device) to be pre-selected when I open a new project, e.g. just downloaded from the Internet. How can I achieve this with the Xcode?

**Not a duplicate since this question is about selecting a default simulator without losing the ability to switch quickly between them.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set the default simulator for new projects in Xcode 7.1 or latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577934/can-i-set-the-default-simulator-for-new-projects-in-xcode-7-1-or-latest)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya not a duplicate at all. The question is not about how to "hide" other simulators, but how to select a specific model as the default one.I still would like to have the ability to switch quickly between the devices, which is lost in the answer you've provided.