# Change default running simulator - react-native?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to change default simulator when building my app,

I'm trying to run this command `react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone XR'`

but it's ignoring me :D and just launch iPhone X I don't know why?

when I open Xcode and choose what simulator i want then press Run icon it's work fine, but i don't need open Xcode every time i want to build my app, it's **hart** my Pc lo

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577934/can-i-set-the-default-simulator-for-new-projects-in-xcode-7-1-or-latest

Comment: @SDushan I did it but not work :/

Answer (score 0):

The Simulator you are trying in command might not be available in your simulators list.
 You can check the list of simulators list with the command:

```
 xcrun simctl list
```

Also, you can start the simulator from the list with command without opening the xcode like:

```
 xcrun simctl boot 4050BA57-C65E-4EDD-9CB3-38AAA9379912
```

**4050BA57-C65E-4EDD-9CB3-38AAA9379912** is the UUID of the simulator you will get it from list.

With React Native to change the default simulator you can try to change the value of `--simulator` option from `node-modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS.js` file

It will be by default like this:

```
{
    command: '--simulator [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set simulator to use',
    default: 'iPhone Xʀ',
  }
```

You can change that **iPhone Xʀ**  to your required simulator.

As you are making these changes inside the `node-modules` it might get changed or affected after `npm or yarn install`.